# How to make Drupal 6 contrib modules works in "wp-content/modules" instead of "sites/all/modules"

Tags: 6, installation

I want to make a new Drupal 6 installation, but I want to make contrib modules works in `wp-content/modules` instead of `sites/all/modules`.

Hacking may works, but I'm not so familiar with Drupal coding. I need to know best way and what file to hack.

Comment: What's the purpose of running them in `wp-content/modules`?

Comment: Just for fun and make script kiddies confuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. Drupal scans recursively for modules in:

```
/modules                             Intended for Core's usage only.
/sites/all/modules                   Modules used by all your sites.
/sites/[site-name]/modules           Site specific modules.
/profiles/[current-profile]/modules  Current profile specific modules.
```

Sure you can hack core if you *really* want to force core to look somewhere else, though I must say I see little value in this, and strongly discourage it.

The relevant code is in /includes/module.inc and you can follow the current logic from module_load_all().

Comment: I agree about the little value. Using a directory named "wp-content" doesn't mean to make the hackers think the site is using WordPress. There are other things that allow to detect when a site is using Drupal.